# Strange Behaviour - $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] value returning 404.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, unix

I have encountered a really odd occurrence. I recently added the following line to my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

This is the ONLY line in the file.

I have a php function that records the value of $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] when a user accesses the site for the purposes of tracking the entry url and path they take while on the site.
The value of $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] has always been correct up until I added the .htaccess line. Now it shows 404.php as the value of $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] when a user accesses the site. When they go to another page, the page name is correct the first time in $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] but then replaces the value with 404.php.

Any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: Have you checked apache configuration (e.g. vhosts if it's vhost entry) as well?

Comment: @bjauy Not sure that I can check or modify anything there. I am hosted @ Hostgator.com. I have talked with their tech support but didn't resolve much there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently at hostgator.com their servers default 404 page is set to 404.shtml.

So to correct the issue, I added the following to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.shtml$ $1.php
```